# Formula for combining text if there are duplicate numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have [a table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQEG_rY1FOxhgKZA7LdvdPBCEWuj_7vpwNLki-Tz3rA/edit#gid=0) to combine text with conditions if in column A there is a duplicate number, then in the text in column B combined.
The formula that I have made like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,A2)>1,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:B),"")
```

But the results do not match, the results I want in column E.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **paste in a cell on the first row:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(((COUNTIF(A2:A, A2)<>
 COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$A$2:A"), A2:A))+(MATCH(A2:A, $A$2:$A, 0)<
 ROW(A2:A)-1))>1, TRUE, ), )=TRUE,
 {""; IF((COUNTIF($A$2:$A, $A$2:$A)>1), B2:B, )&
      IF((COUNTIF($A$2:$A, $A$2:$A)>1), B3:B, )}, ))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this formula not apply if the duplicate number is more than 2?

Comment: I guess it does not if there are 2+ consequential duplicates in A column

Comment: Ok thanks for help sir. Problem solved.